# Extjs xml model hasmany associations

Tags: xml, extjs4, nested, associations

There 2 Ext.data.models (nested):

```
Ext.define('App.Model.Permission', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    belongsTo: 'Roles',
    fields: [{ name: 'Controller', mapping: '@Controller' }, 'Ptype'],    
});

    Ext.define('App.Model.Roles', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'Id',
    hasMany: { model: 'Permission', name: 'Permissions', associationKey: 'Permissions' },    
    fields: [{ name: 'Id', mapping: '@Id' }, 'Name', 'Description']
});
```

Store object- Ext.store

```
 rolesstore = Ext.create('App.Data.Lstore', {
            model: 'App.Model.Roles',
            autoLoad: false,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '/Cache/roles.xml',
                reader: {
                    type: 'xml',
                    record: 'Role'                
                }
            }
        });
```

part of xml file for data loading

> ```
>    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>     <Roles>
>       <Role Id="11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111">
>         <Usercreate>430d4bda-4c0c-4e5a-a443-b7091ef1e98c</Usercreate>
>         <Dateedit>01.01.0001</Dateedit>
>         <Name>Администратор</Name>
>         <Description>Роль администратора</Description>
>         <Permissions>
>           <Permission Controller="PurchaseController">
>             <Ptype>2</Ptype>
>           </Permission>
>           <Permission Controller="ContractController">
>             <Ptype>2</Ptype>
>           </Permission>
>           <Permission Controller="PlanController">
>             <Ptype>2</Ptype>
>           </Permission>
>           <Permission Controller="ApprovalController">
>             <Ptype>2</Ptype>
>           </Permission>
>           <Permission Controller="AdminController">
>             <Ptype>2</Ptype>
>           </Permission>
>           <Permission Controller="DictionaryController">
>             <Ptype>2</Ptype>
>           </Permission>
>         </Permissions>
>       </Role>
> </Roles>
> ```

While loading data to store only 'Roles' model is storing without nesting 'Permission' models?

Where's mistake?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It, just doesn't work this way. The guides say that you have to call the nested association explicitly Roles.Permissions().
see the [guide](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/data) or [example](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/guides/data/examples/associations_validations/app.js).